# SublimeText3で、SublimeREPL:pythonを使う際にpythonのバージョンを変更できません

Tags: python, sublimetext

pytnon2系とpython3系を保持しつつ
SublimeTextREPLでpython2と3を切り替える方法はどうすればよいでしょうか？

現状について以下のとおりです。
python2と3の両方をインストールしてあります。
version

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

which

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

python3を build system に追加して、メニューからそれを選択しました

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.python",
    "file_regex": "file \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]+)",
    "env": {"LANG": "ja_JP.UTF-8"}
}
```

REPLを起動した状態です

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

REPLを python3で使用するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？